# join tables with parent ID

Tags: mysql, types, parent-child

I need some advice in mysql let say we have 3 tables :

deletionlog:

this table show all soft deleted threads and post and the date of deleted time:

```
primaryid   type      dateline
       12   thread    1372789192
       13   thread    1372860700
       15   thread    1372798567
       16   thread    1372818402
       17   thread    1372931230
       37   post      1372790038
       43   post      1372798587
```

thread:

this table show all threads and its fourmid:

```
threadid   forumid  
      12         2
      13         2
      14         2
      15         4
      16         2
      17         2
```

post:

this table show all posts and its threadid:

```
    postid  threadid  
    35        12
    36        13
    37        13
    38        13
    39        12
    40        12
    41        14
    42        14
    43        14
    44        15
    45        16
    46        17
```

and what I want is to show the last date of deleted thread and deleted post joind with other tables information like forumid:

```
primaryid   type     forumid    dateline
       17   thread         2    1372931230
       43   post           2    1372931230
```

OK I managed to get the last deleted date of posts and threads like this :

```
SELECT        *
FROM          deletionlog AS a
INNER JOIN     
(
    SELECT    type, Max(dateline) AS dateline
    FROM      deletionlog
    GROUP BY  type
) AS b
ON            a.type = b.type
AND           a.dateline = b.dateline
WHERE b.type in('thread','post')";
```

but this only one table I want also to join table thread and post to extract the fourmid so any suggestion?

Comment: If you put you table into 2-nd normal form, splitting `deletionlog` into deleted_threads and deleted_posts, creating valid foreign keys, the request would be trivial. Now struggle with complexity and anomalies, that you have yourself created.

Comment: the thing is i want to extract the fourmID of the last deleted thread and post and show it in main page of my vBulletin in the right fourm section and this is the only way that i found is possible ..

Comment: for example: main page
fourm1test: lastDth: 17 , date:132537726, lastDpo: 43 ,date :152437637
fourm2test : lastDth: 18 , date:13456686, lastDpo: 50 ,date :434567889

Comment: Please, provide SQL fiddle for your tables structures and sample data. So, that people could test their answers before they post them.

Comment: the structures is based on vBulletin 4 mysql databse and not important to provide me accurate answers just Principles methods

Comment: I wrote 2 requests, joined by union, cause the same field: deletionlog.primaryid references 2 different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the database structure, you provided, doesn't even comply with 2-nd Normal form. So, I had to write this ugly request, using a UNION:

```
SELECT
    deletionlog.primaryid,
    deletionlog.type,
    thread.forumid,
    deletionlog.dateline
FROM
    deletionlog
INNER JOIN
    thread
ON
    deletionlog.primaryid=thread.threadid
WHERE
    deletionlog.type='thread'
GROUP BY
    deletionlog.type
HAVING
    MAX(deletionlog.dateline)

UNION

SELECT
    deletionlog.primaryid,
    deletionlog.type,
    thread.forumid,
    deletionlog.dateline
FROM
    deletionlog
INNER JOIN
    post
ON
    deletionlog.primaryid=post.postid
INNER JOIN
    thread
ON
    post.threadid=thread.threadid
WHERE
    deletionlog.type='post'
GROUP BY
    deletionlog.type
HAVING
    MAX(deletionlog.dateline)
```